# DropDownList mvc3 selected value doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I got a question concerning a DropDownList with a selected value.

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.weekForEachDayService[6].serviceId, new SelectList    (ViewBag.DayService, "Value", "Text"))
```

As you can see I have a service that is related to a week with a table weekForEachService.

When I run this it never uses the serviceId inside the SelectList.

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.weekForEachDayService[6].serviceId, new SelectList    (ViewBag.DayService, "Value", "Text",m => m.weekForEachDayService[6].serviceId))
```

I also tried something like this but then I get the Error message cannot convert type lambda to object. Usually when I use a DropDownList it automatically selects the correct value, but with this related table I think it's necessary to put the selected value in the list.

Thanks you for helping

Comment: Thanks for the tip i always used the answer useful button but forgot to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the lambda expression that you are using is complex and involves array indexers the `DropDownListFor` helper cannot determine the selected value. It only works with simple property access lambda expressions.

In this case you could pass the selected value as 4th argument to the `SelectList` constructor, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.weekForEachDayService[6].serviceId, 
    new SelectList(
        ViewBag.DayService, 
        "Value", 
        "Text",
        Model.weekForEachDayService[6].serviceId
    )
)
```